# How to build visual studio solution file .sln command line with selected project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have .sln file which has around 352 projects. 
I have created batch file below
    "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/msbuild.exe myproj.sln /nologo /t:Build /p:Configuration="Debug" /property:Platform="Win32"
    pause"

But this builds all the projects from solution. I have configured "Configuration Manager" to unselect unwanted projects or unload project and used above batch file to build but that did not serve the purpose.

I have searched MSBuild options but could not find exact answer.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a solution containing just the projects you want to build. Alternatively you could make an MSBuild .proj file that collects together the projects you want to build:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectsToBuild Include="X.csproj;Child\Y.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects ="@(ProjectsToBuild)" ContinueOnError ="false" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
            <Output ItemName="OutputFiles" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
        </MSBuild>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Derived from http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,ed3a0c98-fdac-4467-9116-5b3bf6755abc.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

MSbuild accepts project name as part of "target" (/t) specification:

```
MSBuild /nologo /t:ProjectName:Build SolutionFile.sln
```

Or, if your project does not depend on other projects in solution, directly use project file with MSBuild:

```
MSBuild /nologo /t:Build ProjectFile.vcxproj
```

This trick works with Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019 and with the latest MSVS 2022.